# Is it possible to select one element from the array and use the attr() if you have elements with similar selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

lets say you have two html elements with the same id , and you need to change the second element's attribute using the attr() jquery method . 
Is it possible to do that because i keep getting an error saying that attr method is not a function .
Note that i have to use the element id .

```
<div id="div_el">ele_one</div>
<div id="div_el">ele_two</div>

<script>

$('#div_el'); // returns an array of all the DOM elements with div_el 
var $el_two = $('#div_el').find(1);

$el_one.attr('style', 'background-color: green;');


</script>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with same `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As itsgoingdown said, you cannot select multiple ID elements. The ID is supposed to be unique. In a pinch, though, you could perhaps do this:

```
var $el_one = $('div#div_el').eq(1)
```

It's selecting on the div first, then the ID, and filtering by index (eg). Fiddle [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/u5g8fk3e/)

Comment: Thanks , exactly what i was looking for . I was not sure if there was a method to parse the dom object element as an object and still be able to reference to the element that we stored .

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use the class , and in this case it will work fine !

- And one error, with your variable name ! $el_one and $el_two
  Example:

```
<div class="div_el">ele_one</div>
<div class="div_el">ele_two</div>
<script>
 // returns the second div in the DOM elements with class div_el 
var $el_two =$('.div_el:eq(0)');
// the browser will modifie the stle property by himself !
$el_one.css('background-color', 'green');
```

Comment: This method also works just fine  . I gave it a try on [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/kevinkid/vtjdkp6q/) .

thanks again